# AccountingDate (ChronoLocalDate) to Instant in java

Tags: java, localdate, date, rfc2445

I'm using the [AccountingDate](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/AccountingDate.html) implemented into this [project](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/package-summary.html).

```
public final class AccountingDate extends AbstractDate implements ChronoLocalDate, Serializable {}
```

Do you know a way to convert an AccountingDate to Instant or LocalDate?

Comment: How does the result of `AccountingDate.toString()` look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AccountingDate` implements `ChronoLocalDate`, which supports all date based `ChronoFields`, so it supports `ChronoFields.EPOCH_DAY`, so `LocalDate.from` works:

```
LocalDate.from(accountingDate)
```

To convert a date to an `Instant`, you need two more pieces of information:

- time
- zone offset

If we assume the time is midnight, and the zone offset being UTC, we can do:

```
accountingDate.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a chrono date, you need to go through the epoch days

This would be e.g. like:

```
AccountingDate accountingDate = ...
LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(accountingDate.toEpochDay())
```